# EATX mobo power slot too big?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I am putting some parts together for a friend and the power supply he gave me is too small for the mother board power. It leaves 4 slots left unused. Does he need a brand new power supply or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your power supply has 20 pins and your motherboard has a 24-pin plug. (Some power supplies have an additional +4 pin connector that attaches to the side of the 20 pin connector.)

If you don't have that +4 connector you need a new power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Look into EPS12v.  Newer and better brands all conform to the standard.